# Unknown quotes around text returned by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Suppose `localhost` points to folder `www`, the folder struct:

```
www/
    file/test.cpp
    index.html
```

I would like to dynamically load `test.cpp` in `index.html` and render it with `highlight.js`.

Here is the code in `index.html`:

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'file/test.cpp',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(code) {
        $('#content').html($('<pre>').append($('<code>').text(code)));
    }
});
<script>
```

But what i got is:

```
<pre><code>
"
  ...here is the content of test.cpp...
"
</code></pre>
```

**Notice the quotes around the content of `test.cpp`**? How do I got rid of them? They are not supposed to be there.  Because when I use `console.log`, those quotes don't show.  I think I must miss something here,  anyone could help me out?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the mime type (Content-Type header) returned by the server?

Comment: @wdosanjos I used `jekyll server` to develop locally, so the default type should be `text` I think.

Comment: Try adding `dataType : 'text'` to your `$.ajax` call.

Comment: @wdosanjos Thanks. But quotes are still there.

Comment: `success: function(txt)` -> you should use `txt` not `code`... make sure your datatype is set correctly, that your Ajax processing file isn't **adding** the quotes, and add `.trim()` to the end of your `$('#content')...` call to trim off the extra spaces

Comment: Where `code` comes from on `$('#content').html($('<pre>').append($('<code>').text(code)));`?

Comment: @scrowler Sorry for mistyping. Changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the quotes appear because the css of the tag. you need to call the script of highlight.js to highlight the code. try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file/test.cpp',
    success: function(txt) {
        $('#content').html($('<pre>').append($('<code>').text(code)));
          $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey tons of thanks, could you explain a bit more? It worked adding the `hljs` stuff.

Comment: in the page of the plugin http://highlightjs.org/usage/. you can se the usage of it. is easy you can init at the start of the page or make your custom init.